# Partial differential equation without substitution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

With explicit direct substitution one can show that 
$$u(x,t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{\frac{(x-1)}{\sqrt{4t}}}^{\frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt{4t}}}e^{-u^2}du+\sqrt{t}\Big( e^{-\frac{(z+1)^2}{4t}}- e^{-\frac{(z-1)^2}{4t}} \Big)$$
is the solution of the equation $u_t=u_{xx}$, $-\infty<x<\infty$, $t>0$ with initial condition $u(x,0)=x$ if $-1<x<1$, and $u(x,0)=0$ otherwise.

I'm looking for a better idea to solve this PDE. I mean without substitution.

Can anyone help me?

Also, I want to find the limit of $u(x,t)$ when $t$ approaches to positive infinity. I have no idea how to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of $u_t = u_{xx}$ for $t > 0$, $-\infty < x < \infty$ with initial data $u(0,x)=f(x)$ where $f$ is absolutely integrable is
$$
       u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-y)^2/4t}f(y)dy.
$$
In your case $f(y)=y$ for $-1 < y < 1$ and is $0$ otherwise. You can first rewrite the above using $y=x+w$:
$$
   u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-(x-y)^2/4t}ydy \\
    =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-1+x}^{1+x}e^{-w^2/4t}(x+w)dw
$$
Then you can scale $v=w/\sqrt{4t}$:
$$
    u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{\frac{-1+x}{\sqrt{4t}}}^{\frac{-1+x}{\sqrt{4t}}}e^{-v^2}(x+\sqrt{4t}v)\sqrt{4t}dv
$$
Then you can integrate the term with $v$ in it because $\frac{d}{dv}e^{-v^2}=-2ve^{-v^{2}}$.